# Overlapping text in Database Schema SEDE

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, data-explorer, schema

Over at [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/new), there is overlapping text in the Database Schema under Close-As-Off-Topic-Reason-Types:

[image]

that makes it really hard to read.  This is also happening underneath "Pending Flags", and seemingly with every long line in the schema.  This would be fine if you could increase the width of the list as you can with the height, which would in theory separate the lines, but you can't.  Can we fix this, please?

---

**UPDATE:**

I have found that [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/254336/sede-database-schema-overlapping-text) post is almost exactly the same as mine, but steady on with duplicate votes.  [This](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/254336/sede-database-schema-overlapping-text#comment830441_254336) comment says that it will be fixed, but that question was asked more than five years ago, and in that time the problem has not been resolved.

---

**UPDATE 2:**

It seems that [having the ability to increase the width of the schema](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/353814/add-the-ability-to-increase-width-of-database-schema-sede?noredirect=1&lq=1) would help.  I changed a little CSS/HTML, and came up with this:

[image]

Although mine is a little cruder than it could be.  This is just an example.

Comment: I checked but that per table fieldlist is a dl (definition list) with a dt for the fieldname and a dd for the type. I tried some css fu but using a word-break for the overflow messes up the horizontal alignment of the rest. overflow:hidden works but then there is no way that you can find out what the full name of the field is (there is no title attribute on the dt element). If anything, we first need to work out what an acceptable fix is.

Comment: @rene Probably `overflow:hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis;` with a title for each, I guess

Comment: @TimStone yeah, that will work. That css rule looks fine. And then we need the title attribute [here](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.DataExplorer/blob/master/App/StackExchange.DataExplorer/Views/Query/Editor.cshtml#L68). That would be a quick fix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on what I suggested in the comments and what was [amended by Tim Stone](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/353756/overlapping-text-in-database-schema-sede#comment1182624_353756) I've gone ahead and created [this pull request](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.DataExplorer/pull/103).

This adds CSS rules to handle the text overflow and introduces a title attribute on the `<dt>` element.

I consider this for now a quick-fix while we come up with a better suited solution that also works for touch devices (title only works on hover which can't be done on tablets and phones).

This is now deployed and live in rev 2020.12.13.80.