# Why are accepted answers now rendering with a dark green background?

Tags: support, accepted-answer, userscript

At some point over the past few days, I've noticed that accepted answers across the network now have a green background, like this:

[image: Screenshot of the craziness]

Why is that?

I'm running Chrome 84 on Windows 10, with [StackUnderflow](https://github.com/MarcinOrlowski/StackUnderflow) installed in TamperMonkey.

*(Please excuse the red border and annotation, but otherwise the screenshot looks like it's part of the actual MSE page. )*

Comment: @Sonic Surely someone asking this after encountering it in the wild would have reported it as a bug? I suppose my wording was a little too "passive aggressive" in that sense to make that clear :P There's an implied "this is not right"/"something has gone wrong" in there ;)

Comment: It's not an actual bug report with the SE software, as your answer says.

Comment: @SonictheMaskedWerehog Ah, but the question doesn't know that! It _is_ a bug report, even though the answer is "it's not a bug". :) I'd prefer we use the appropriate tag for the question so people can find it more easily.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not anything to do wih our software. Meta is not the place for bug reports about third-party software. Consider visiting [Stack Apps](https://stackapps.com).

Comment: @animuson To me it seems completely reasonable that someone might have encountered this thinking it was related to the new redesign/styling (despite being wrong), so I wanted to help them out by putting a canonical Q&A _right where they would be looking_. But I guess that was wrong. Sorry to have wasted your time.

Comment: And in case you were wondering, this sort of nonsense is why SE has a reputation for being unwelcoming.

Comment: Before filing a bug report here, it is expected for users to disable any extensions or scripts they're running, if they could interfere with the thing being reported. Had a potential reporter of a bug did that, they would have seen that it was caused by an external script and the bug would have never been filed.

Answer (score 6):

Actually, this is *not* a Stack Exchange bug… nor is it, strictly speaking, a bug at all!

The default value for the `cfg_highlightAcceptedAnswer` configuration option in the StackUnderflow script is `true`, which is intended to cause this effect.

However, until StackUnderflow v1.2.1, [this configuration option did not work](https://github.com/MarcinOrlowski/StackUnderflow/issues/17), so you would not have noticed the behaviour. When TamperMonkey updated the script on (or after) the 4th September, the style change would have suddenly kicked into gear.

It looks weird because it doesn't match the current SE stylesheets (probably because it hasn't been seen, therefore nor updated, in some time).

You can turn it off by going into the script and setting `cfg_highlightAcceptedAnswer` to `false`:

[image: Screenshot of the relevant configuration option in the StackUnderflow script]

Then it all goes away:

[image: Screenshot of the same answer as it should appear]

Comment: I didn't see a green background two days ago when I accepted the answer [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/353756/overlapping-text-in-database-schema-sede).  I haven't had to fiddle with anything.

Comment: @Ollie Then perhaps your script hadn't updated, or you already had the option set to `false`, or you had not enabled the script for MSE.